# Check kafka broker is active or not in python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am working on Kafka in python using kafka-python. I want to know that can I fetch the following information regarding kafka broker in python itself and if yes then how?

1. Number of active and inactive Kafka brokers with the broker name

Comment: Brokers have ids, not names, but what do you mean by "active"? Because if the broker is offline, then it wouldn't be known to the rest of the cluster

Comment: @OneCricketeer you are right. I just want to fetch the broker id of the online broker in python. i.e. I just want some method to check it in python.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the AdminClient class in the confluent_kafka python  library since that's what you'd use with the Java API